# calendar view in android

Tags: android, calendar

i need to display a **calendar** control in my app.I can not use google calender and other third party calendars.i want to display the selected date on the calender in a textview. i have searched for documents about calender view in net.but did not get anything.can anybody help me to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the full-activity implementation, you can try this post;
http://w2davids.wordpress.com/android-simple-calendar/

Answer (score 0):

To display a calendar not using Google Calendar you could try [android-calendar-view](http://code.google.com/p/android-calendar-view/)

Comment: i already gone through that link...but did not see any code snippet for that

Comment: @seethalakshmi: You can find it's code here at http://code.google.com/p/android-calendar-view/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fsrc%2Fcom%2Fexina%2Fandroid%2Fcalendar

Answer (score 0):

Download [Calendar v0.5.0](http://code.google.com/p/android-calendar-view/downloads/detail?name=Calendar.v0.5.0.zip&can=2&q=)
and follow that howto : [How To Use](http://code.google.com/p/android-calendar-view/wiki/HowToUse)

Answer (score 0):

I made this Calendar Library for Android as part of my side project. Below is the link to the github and it has all the instructions on how to use it. If you still come across any difficulty implementing it let me know. Happy to help.

https://github.com/ik024/CalendarLibrary

[image] [image]

Hope it helps.